# Interface design pattern / Java / Seam

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, seam, interceptor

Is this possible somehow?

```
@Name("geolocationService")
public interface GeolocationService
{
   @Query("SELECT g FROM Geolocation geolocation INNER JOIN geolocation.deployment deployment WHERE geolocation.ipStart <= INET_ATON(:ipAddress) AND deployment.active = TRUE")
   Geolocation findByIpAddress(@NamedParameter("ipAddress")final String ipAddress);
}


public GeolocationAction
{
  @In
  private GeolocationService geolocationService;

  @RequestParameter("ipAddress")
  private String ipAddress;

  @Out
  private Geolocation geolocation;

  public void find()
  {
    geolocation = geolocationService.findByIpAddress(ipAddress);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do this without implementing the interface?  What is required to make that work?  I want to maintain less and do more.

If I can intercept invocations of the geolocationService then I am golden, how would I do that?  I don't want it to ever be instantiated, so it will always be null (I don't want the @Name and @In annotations either then).

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, I wrap all methods in my services.  I automatically find the query they're looking for and inject the parameters (either named or indexed).  This isn't as clean as I'd like it, but there is room for improvement.

I write an interface as well as a implementation with no code in the body except return(null);

Walter

Answer (score 0):

First of all an interface is not supposed to be a seam component. How will you instantiate that seam component (interface)?

Secondly. You cannot use `@Query` like that.

Third, what are you actually asking? 
I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Query is my annotation.  In a later iteration, I was simply using NamedQuery annotations and then creating the named query based on the method name.

It doesn't need to be a Seam component, I just want to give a query parameters without having to write the implementation which will be redundant work.

Walter

Comment: I was originally thinking about writing a startup listener that would create the necessary queries / components, but all I want is a parameterized method without writing the method itself.  In another project I worked on, we used interceptors to automatically get the appropriate query and pass in the arguments from simply an interface.  I would do that approach if I felt the interceptor would not add too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what Seam is and I don't see a nice simple one paragraph description so I might be talking about something completely irrelevant.

I've [have played a little](http://ihaztehcodez.michael-lloyd-lee.me.uk/2009/10/my-nifty-idea.html) with an idea like for running SQL procedures using nothing but a few annotations. The implementation comes from a [dynamic proxy](http://github.com/mlk/magic-procedures/blob/master/src/com/blogspot/ihaztehcodez/magic/SQLHandler.java).

Comment: Yeah, I do need dynamic proxies - I am using JBoss Seam with Javassist, so I would probably need to read up on Javassist or JBoss AOP at the very least.

I would also like to run some comparisons to see how much overhead it entails for running the exact same query.  For a long while, I used Seam Entity Queries which are configured via XML, or as I did, I wrote my own startup listener which created them from annotations.  In addition, you can also extend the class and statically set your query there.

I like the idea of named queries being declared, but not necessarily on the entity bean.